# print both key and value to the console

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to render a coherent error message on a form, but my errors are like:

**OBJECT:**

```
{ "email": [ "can't be blank" ], "password": [ "can't be blank" ] }
```

**INTENDED MESSAGE**

```
email can't be blank
password can't be blank
```

so, How can I take that object and transform into the "*intended message*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `for` loop to achieve this. Concatenate the key and the message.

```js
var json = { "email": [ "can't be blank" ], "password": [ "can't be blank" ] }

for ( var key in json ) {
    console.log( key + " " + json[key] );
}
```